# Number of arguments coinciding during Java method overloading

Tags: java, overloading

I came across a question where we need to calculate the volume of a sphere, a cylinder, and a cone using method overloading. The following is my code which is absolutely alright:

```
import java.util.*;
class Vol_Sph_Cyl_Con
{
    void calc_volume(double sp_rd)
    {
        double volume=(4*3.14*(Math.pow(sp_rd,3)))/3;
        System.out.println("Volume of the sphere is "+volume+" cc");    
    }
    void calc_volume(double cyl_rd, double cyl_he)
    {
        double volume=3.14*(Math.pow(cyl_rd,2))*cyl_he;
        System.out.println("Volume of the cylinder is "+volume+" cc");
    }
    void calc_volume(double con_rd,double con_he,double pie)
    {
        double volume=(pie*(Math.pow(con_rd,2))*con_he)/2;
        System.out.println("Volume of the cone is "+volume+" cc");
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        Vol_Sph_Cyl_Con ob=new Vol_Sph_Cyl_Con();
        double sp_rad=0.0;
        do 
        {
            System.out.println("Enter radius of sphere to calculate the volume (in centimetres)");
            sp_rad=sc.nextDouble();
            if (sp_rad<=0)
            {
                System.out.println("Error!");
            }
        }while (sp_rad<=0);
        ob.calc_volume(sp_rad);
        double cyl_rad=0.0, cyl_hei=0.0;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the radius and the height of cylinder respectively to calculate volume (in centimetres)");
            cyl_rad=sc.nextDouble();
            cyl_hei=sc.nextDouble();
            if (cyl_rad<=0 || cyl_hei<=0)
            {
                System.out.println("Error!");
            }
        }while (cyl_rad<=0 || cyl_hei<=0);
        ob.calc_volume(cyl_rad,cyl_hei);
        double con_rad=0.0, con_hei=0.0, pi=3.14;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter radius and height of cone respectively to calculate volume (in centimetres)");
            con_rad=sc.nextDouble();
            con_hei=sc.nextDouble();
            if (con_rad<=0 || con_hei<=0)
            {
                System.out.println("Error!");
            }
        }while (con_rad<=0 || con_hei<=0);
        ob.calc_volume(con_rad,con_hei,pi);
      }
   }
```

The programme is absolutely fine but the problem is, as this is for a school project, I cannot pass the argument 'pie' in the method which calculates the value of cone as we are not allowed to pass explicitly something which is not required. But if I don't do that the number of arguments coincides. Is there a way to solve this, or is it just a problem with the question?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar because we are supposed to do the task using only method overloading

Comment: @ShinjineeMaiti whoops, sorry. I guess I can't read today.

Comment: @Zircon do you mean the second sentence?

Comment: Kind of a cheesy suggestion, but you could make one radius a `float` and leave the other one as a `double`

Comment: @Zircon well, this is not a bad idea....thanks!!

Comment: Consider using `Math.PI` rather than 3.14.

Comment: @Bathsheba but I guess that doesn't solve my problem??

Comment: IMHO, it is a problem with the question. Using just method overloading for this is horrible. What if you want to calculate the volume for more bodies? Say, for regular pythagorean bodies. It does not make sense that all those methods should have a different number of parameters. Consider using a class hierarchy instead.

Comment: @Tomer but I'm using one method only for one figure?

Comment: Your cone volume computation is off: you need to divide by 3, not by 2.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight this was so nice of you to point out........guess I got totally messed up!

Comment: @ShinjineeMaiti: it solves an important numerical issue: currently your results will only be accurate to 2 significant figures. Archimedes did better than that when chucking stuff into his bathtub.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment your arguments are the defining values for the geometric bodies you want to calculate the volume of. If you have two, or more, geometric bodies sharing the same defining value types you will loose, as you cannot distinguish between them based on the types only as they are equal. As it has been pointed out by [tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639625/tobias-k).

What you could do to solve this is to add a representation for each of the geometric bodies you need to your code. Those can then be used as the single argument to your volume calculation method.

So for your example you would need: a sphere, a cylinder, and a cone class.

```
public class Sphere {
}

public class Cylinder {
}

public class Cone {
}
```

As this is a homework, we should leave it to you to think about how to design those classes. Your overloaded method would look like so:

```
void calc_volume(Sphere sphere) {}
void calc_volume(Cylinder cylinder) {}
void calc_volume(Cone cone) {}
```

As you see, there will be no further limitation on the number of geometric objects you could handle using this design.

Comment: Either this way, or let the different `GeometricObject` classes have a method `calc_volume`, but this way it's closer to what seems to be the asked in the assignment.

Comment: @tobias_k: Exactly

Comment: There is no real need to for those  classes to implement the same interface

Comment: @C.Champagne: Bad habit of over-engineering. I removed them already. To easy to confuse beginners with something like this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make three methods resolve on two sets of arguments: if you are to pass the height and the radius for both a cone and a cylinder, you would have to change the name of one of the methods.

However, you can generalize your problem in a different way: rather than having two separate methods to compute volume for cones and for cylinders, have a single method that computes volume of a [*frustum*](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/Frustum/Frustum.cone.html) of a cone, which can be generalized to both a cylinder (top radius = bottom radius) and a cone (top radius = 0):

[image]

This leaves you with only two methods - one for the sphere, and one for cones and cylinders:

```
void calc_volume(double top, double bottom, double height) {
    double v = Math.PI * height * (top*top + top*bottom + bottom*bottom) / 3;
     System.out.println("Volume is " + v + " cc");
}
```

When you call this method to compute the volume for the cone, pass `0` for `top` and base radius for `bottom`. For cylinder, pass base radius for both `top` and `bottom`.

Answer (score 0):

Some people mentioned in the comments that using method overloading in this case is quite ugly. I personally agree with that.

Anyway, you can create "argument" classes to pass your parameters so that you will need only one argument at a time.

example for a sphere:

```
public class SphereArguments {
    private double radius;

    /**
     * @param radius
     */
    public SphereArguments(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    /**
     * @return the radius
     */
    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
}
```

and `calc_volume` would become:

```
void calc_volume(SphereArguments arg)
{
    double volume=(4*Math.PI *(Math.pow(arg.getRadius(),3)))/3;
    System.out.println("Volume of the sphere is "+volume+" cc");    
}
```

and the call :

```
ob.calc_volume(new SphereArguments(sp_rad));
```

You will have of course to do some the same way with `CylinderArguments` class for the cylinder and 'ConeArguments' class for the cone.

Note also that Java names are in [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) by convention so `calc_volume` should become `calcVolume`...

Comment: I don't see how this is any different from [@pintxo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37729211/1639625)...

Comment: @tobias_k I was still writing the answer when pintxo submitted his. I was just too slow but I didn't want to delete my answer anyway. The only difference is that I my classes don't implement any specific interface which would be better but not strictly necessary either.